# Android ActionBar (ActionBarCompat) Spinner Dropdown list ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am currently working ActionBar (ActionBarCompat) oriented project, I Need some Clarification about actionbar.

I am using spinner layout like this,

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

My code,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  OnItemSelectedListener{
    private boolean mAlternateTitle = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerList);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
}
```

It is displaying normal spinner in my android galaxy ace. I need output like given below,
Is that position android 2.3. Please give suggestion.

[image]

thanks.

Comment: You want the bar for android 2.3? http://actionbarsherlock.com/ Is a library that supports such. It mimics the behaviour on devices that dont support it.

Comment: Is it possible action bar using support library??

Comment: Yes, use ActionBarSherlok to get this spinner. You can see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737500/show-dropdown-programatically-in-actionbar-actionbarsherlock/11794124#11794124

Comment: The support library doesn't support it im afraid. But sherlock is easy to use. See Georgy answer for example code.

Answer (score 9):

Try this code .
 **In   menu/main.xml :**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" >
```

**in Activity :**

```
private MenuItem mSpinnerItem1 = null;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


    MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    mSpinnerItem1 = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_spinner1);
    View view1 = mSpinnerItem1.getActionView();
    if (view1 instanceof Spinner)
    {
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view1;
        spinner.setAdapter(ad1);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How to use getActionView if I'm supporting android 2.3?

Comment: the line:
View view1 = mSpinnerItem1.getActionView();
requires API 11+. To make it work with API 4+, write:
View view1 = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSpinnerItem1);

Answer (score 4):

I feel it's time to start migrating from ABS to ABC easily by ActionBarCompat library!

Solution for spinner (Dropdown list) using **ActionBarCompat** library

```
private void setupSpinner(MenuItem item) {
    //  item.setVisible(getSupportActionBar().getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        item.setVisible(ab.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        View view = item.getActionView();
        Context context = ab.getThemedContext(); //to get the declared theme
        if (view instanceof Spinner) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.spinner_data,
                    R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            listAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        }
```

make sure you have added following in style.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

More importantly:
menu/main.xml should be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:visible="true"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_user"

        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_contact"/>
       <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_user"

        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/aboutus"/>

</menu>
```

FYI  ActionBarSherlock way we used before:

```
private void setupSpinner(MenuItem item) {
        item.setVisible(getActionBar().getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        View view = item.getActionView();
        if (view instanceof Spinner) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;
            spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.spinner_data,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item));
        }
```

comparing to ABS ABC  you need to set listadapter as `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

to

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using ActionBarCompat, which is only a sample project and is far not enough to be usable.

Try to use open source project [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). I have been used it in several projects, and  it is powerful and easy to use.

Comment: Ya i'm used ActionBarCompat previously, now i'm trying ActionBarSharlock i have one in sharlock, i'm using spinner and applied style **style="@style/Theme.Sherlock"** this one not working displaying normal spinner only, i need above image output using spinner, is it possible??

Comment: @Ramachandran we can use ABC also!! see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you will add spinner to your action bar through menu's xml like this

`android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"`

it will appear just like other menu actions - to the right.

If you want to make it appear to the left, you can do another way.

[image: screenshot]

I'm doing it inside a fragment (but you can do it with activity), and using `Toolbar`, so my code is:

`activity_main.xml` (`theme` and `popupTheme` are important for arrow color) :

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
...
```

`action_bar_spinner_title.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

`action_bar_spinner_list.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Inside fragment:

```
private static final String[] arItems = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", };

private Toolbar toolbar;
private Spinner actionBarSpinner;

public ActionBarSpinnerFragment() {
}

@Nullable @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action_bar_spinner, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if(activity != null) {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            toolbar = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            actionBarSpinner = new Spinner(actionBar.getThemedContext());
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity,
                    R.layout.action_bar_spinner_title, android.R.id.text1, arItems);
            spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.action_bar_spinner_list);
            actionBarSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            actionBarSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    FragmentManager fragMngr = getFragmentManager();
                    if(fragMngr != null) {
                        FragmentTransaction fragTransact = fragMngr.beginTransaction();
                        fragTransact.replace(R.id.frag_frame,
                                TextViewFragment.newInstance(arItems[position]));
                        fragTransact.commit();

                    } else {
                        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "ActionBarSpinnerFragment: FragmentManager == null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
            toolbar.addView(actionBarSpinner);
        } else {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "ActionBarSpinnerFragment.onStart: actionBar == null");
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG,  "ActionBarSpinnerFragment.onStart: activity == null");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(toolbar != null && actionBarSpinner != null) {
        toolbar.removeView(actionBarSpinner);
    } else {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "ActionBarSpinnerFragment: toolbar == " + toolbar
                + "; actionBarSpinner == " + actionBarSpinner);
    }
}
```