# Can't get action view for ActionBar MenuItem using support library

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I recently switched from [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to the [Android Support Library ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), and now I get a null on the action view of a spinner in the action bar.

Here's the code as suggested by the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu); 
  MenuItem spinnerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuNavigateType);
  View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(spinnerItem);// !! view is NULL !!
        ...
}
```

Here's `R.menu.home_menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> 
  ...
  <item 
    android:id="@+id/menuNavigateType"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.Spinner"  />
     ...
</menu>
```

How do I get my action view?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your spinner xml?

Comment: The spinner is defined in the xml I posted above as an actionViewClass.

Comment: U might want to look in android.support.v7.widget package if there is any spinner. There is no Spinner class, so you need to define the right way to class android.widget.Spinner for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but try the following, instead of `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()`, use:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);   
    MenuItem spinnerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuNavigateType);

    View view = spinnerItem.getActionView();
    // ...
    if(view instanceof Spinner) {
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;
        // create your adapter
        // ...
        // set your adapter
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Also for your item, instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Spinner`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuNavigateType"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" >
```

I saw this solution here: [Android ActionBar (ActionBarCompat) Spinner Dropdown list ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526913/android-actionbar-actionbarcompat-spinner-dropdown-list).
Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Filo.  I had the same problem with the code you show above. In fact, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) suggest that it be done as I have shown in the question I posted.

Comment: Yes I knew this. Normally you have to do as you did but something is wrong in this way with `AppCompat`. So, you have the same problem with this example? Edit your question and post the layout of your spinner (as @user2511882 said). Did you have the logcat?

Comment: @Filo, sorry I was wrong, you are correct, your solution worked. I missed the "myapp" namespace for all the items in my xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due most probably to the lack of including the support.v7 library.
Just dont use the myapp. Instead:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menuNavigateType"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"/>
```