# How to implement dropdown from icon actionbar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i am able to get dropdown on action bar, but i i'm not getting how to do the same when i click on icon.

[image]

Here how the drop-down i get by default, but i want the same by clicking on the icon. i.e if i click on left side android icon i want the dropdwon to appear.

is there any way?..

here is my code.

```
package com.example.actionbarsample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      String []data1={"Brainbitz:java","Brainbitz:Android","Brainbitz:Embedded Systems","Brainbitz:PHP"};
      String []data2={"6month Course","3month Course","3month Course","3month Course"};
      Integer[] images={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        MyAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner, data1);

       actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, nav);

      //  Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
       // mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner, data1));
    }

    OnNavigationListener nav = new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int arg0, long arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
};


    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        String[] objects) {
                  super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            label.setText(data1[position]);

            TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            sub.setText(data2[position]);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

            return row;
            }

   }


    }
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11737500/. easiest solutions seems to be to use a custom view navigation instead of the action bar drop down navigation mode.

Comment: @matthias, thanks for the link, i tried lot to get but could not found solution. i have posted source, still i'm not getting any drop down menu. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208285/unable-to-get-custom-spinner-in-android. i'm sure you can find the mistake.. thanks